# Python Regex matching new line

Tags: python, regex

I am new to python and I am trying regex to generate documentation of FORTRAN code. I have to read subroutine name declared in comments and also that written in actual code.

The commented code looks like this:

```
C  
C ....FEW MORE COMMENTS ABOVE  
C  
C  
C SUBROUTINE ( X ,\n  
C              Y,\n  
C              Z)   
C  
C-----------------------------------
```

which is then followed by actual code:

```
 SUBROUTINE ( X, \n  
             Y, \n  
             Z \n  
           )
```

I am not able to figure out how to read the actual code SUBROUTINE declaration . 
My regex for commented code is something like this:

```
re.compile(r"C+ SUBROUTINE (?P<comment>.*?) \nC\n",re.DOTALL)(this works fine)
```

But my regex for actual code returns same thing as above regex:

```
re.compile(r" ^(?!C)SUBROUTINE (?P<comment>.*?) \)")
```

Please correct me.

Comment: Could you clarify if there is supposed to be whitespace before the SUBROUTINE declaration? It was removed in a edit, but from your regex I suspect it was intentional

Comment: yes there can be a whitespace..

Comment: Here is a online regex tester, you can test your regex. http://regexpal.com/

Comment: Please familiarize yourself with the editor, especially about code formatting. Highlight the code and press Ctrl-K to have it formatted correctly instead of trying to do this manually by inserting `<br>` tags etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!C)` where you should be using a lookbehind assertion:

```
re.compile(r" ^(?<!C )SUBROUTINE (?P<comment>.*?) \)")
```

Note that lookbehind assertions in Python need to be fixed width, so this approach only works if there always is exactly one space character between `C` and `SUBROUTINE`.

Comment: what if there can be any space between C and Subroutine? . will /s wont help?

Comment: `\s` matches any *single* whitespace character, so it will help if there could be a tab instead of a space as well. However, it will also match a newline character, so if there is a `C` as the only character in the line before a line that starts directly with `SUBROUTINE`, that regex will also match.

Comment: thanks for your help Tim. But I have got the spaces between start of line and SUBROUTINE. there are fixed spaces though(total 6). I tried with your regex modifying only the spaces. It doesnt work. Also I tried to keep no space. It doesnt work.

Comment: @user3705462: Is there a `C` at the start of the line? Can you provide actual data and the actual regex you're using? Perhaps testing it on a site like http://regex101.com will help you find the problem.